# Create a list from javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a list in my html with the results I get from a JavaScript function. 
My code is the following

```
function (data) {
                for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                    alert(data[i].name)
                    $("resultados").innerHTML = data[i].name+"\n"
                }
            }
```

Comment: and what's the problem with it? Could you explain further and post a fiddle, please?

Comment: data does not always return the same amount of results. I need to print those results in my html file as a list, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: is `#resultados` a `ul` or `ol` element? could you post the content of `data` object?

Comment: resultados is a div element in the html. The content of the data object is {[id:"1", name:"the_Real_Name"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `document.createElement()` to create the list in the DOM:

```
        function createList(data) {
        var ul=document.createElement("ul");
        for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
            var li=document.createElement("li");
            li.value=data[i].name;
            li.innerHTML=data[i].name;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(ul);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

And to make each element as a link you just need to format the content of the `li` element like this:

```
li.innerHTML="<a href=\"yourUrlGoesHere\">"+data[i]+"</a>";
```

See the [**DEMO Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/j9fkrLt3/).

Comment: and if I want those names in the li to be a link, how can I do it?

Comment: @AsierGR just change the innerHTML of your `li`, see my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Code uses `map` and `join` functions.

```
function (data) {
  $("resultados").innerHTML = data.map(function(d){ return d.name }).join("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're overwriting the innerHTML every time.

Try:

```
$("resultados").append(data[i].name+"<br />");
```

Also, my example may not work because `$("resultados")` doesn't seem like it's going to match anything. Maybe you meant `$("#resultados")`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function (data) {
  var htmlString = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      // store the current data item to a temp variable.
      htmlString += data[i].name + "<br>";
  }
  $("#resultados").html(htmlString);
}
```